# When to use "ĝin" and "tion"

Tags: word-usage, correlatives

This is the logic I follow:

- Nouns are replaced with *ĝin*

> Mi ŝatas la filmon.
>
> Mi ŝatas ĝin.

- While *tio* replaces longer phrases.

> Mi ŝatas, ke la filmo finiĝas feliĉe.
>
> Mi ŝatas tion.

I see this most often as responses to questions. Here are some more examples:

> Kiu faris la foton?
> Mi faris ĝin.
>
> Kiu purigis la banĉambron?
> Mi faris tion.
>
> Kiu planis la ekskurson?
> Mi planis ĝin.
>
> Ĉu vi iros al la kinejo ĉi-vespere?
> Mi planas tion.

However, I've seen people use these interchangeably. Is my way of thinking wrong?

Comment: I left an answer below in which I basically confirm what you're thinking in your question.  If there was something else you wanted to know or if my answer could be clearer, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly a lot of overlap - but notice that in your examples, *ĝin* generally replaces nouns and noun phrases, while *tion* replaces verbs and phrases that include verbs.

Comment: Ah right! Noun phrases vs phrases with verbs. I was having trouble finding the correct way to name these categories. What do you mean with *generally*, are there exceptions? Is this a rule or an observation? Could you find a source that mentions/explains this?

Comment: Let me see if I can find something formal. For now, I looked at the examples you chose, reflected on my experience, and took a (very quick) look around to see if anything contradicted that.